# Moving files in an Azure SMB File Share from linux

Tags: linux, azure, smb, fileshare

I have a few Azure SMB File Shares mounted on a linux VM.

In one of those file shares I have two folders, one called *download* and another called *loaded*.

Files get dropped in *download*, they get processed and moved into *loaded*. But sometimes we have to move the files from *loaded* to *download* again from our laptops (running Windows). And when we do this, the files can't move back to *loaded*.

Essentially:

1. I mount file-share
2. I run `mv /mnt/file-share/download/file.txt /mnt/file-share/loaded/file.txt`
3. I drag and drop file.txt from *loaded* to *download* from my laptop

Up to here everything works. But when I try to run `mv /mnt/file-share/download/file.txt /mnt/file-share/loaded/file.txt` again, it returns:

`mv: /mnt/file-share/download/file.txt /mnt/file-share/loaded/file.txt are the same file`

If I now umount and mount again file-share it works. So this makes me thing that it's a caching issue.

So I tried mounting with `cache=none` but it still does the same thing.

Any sugestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the **noserverino** option while mounting the share fixed the issue.